# DevExpress theme to be set for windows controls

Tags: winforms, devexpress, themes

How could I set or change the style of windows default controls(Like button,textbox etc.) using the DevExpress themes/skins?

Application: Windows

Framework: .NET Framework 4.0

DevExpress WinForms Version: 14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devexpress doesn't supports skinning of regular winforms controls. You need to use their own controls to get the application skinned/themed.

For `TextBox` you use `TextEdit`, for `Button` you use `SimpleButton` and so on.

But you can [read the skin element colors at runtime and apply yourself](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18488).

Sample code from the above link(in case link rot in future):

```
DevExpress.Skins.Skin currentSkin;
DevExpress.Skins.SkinElement element;
string elementName;
currentSkin = DevExpress.Skins.CommonSkins.GetSkin(defaultLookAndFeel1.LookAndFeel);
elementName = DevExpress.Skins.CommonSkins.SkinTextBorder;
element = currentSkin[elementName];
Color skinBorderColor = element.Border.All;
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting the colors style from their skin/theme?

Comment: @Ganee yes possible. Ive done that with success earlier. I've updated the answer with link which will help you to get the skin colors.

Comment: Thanks sriram for your support.